adding custom scopes to specific clients in WSO2
I have multiple client-applications calling a backend behind a WSO2 APIM. This backend do a scope validation to allow certain operations (it verifies presence of scope). So I'm trying to handle custom scope assignment in WSO2.
I went to create a custom scope in wso2 identity server > manage > OIDC Scopes without adding claims, then went to my client settings in wso2 identity server > identity > my-client > OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration, to add the custom scope to this client, but couldn't find any option that allow this assignment .
Am I doing something wrong ? How to achieve this ?
ps: I'm using WSO2 IS 5.7.0
